# How does Boost.Python work?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

How is Python able to call C++ objects when the interpreter is C and has been built w/ a C compiler?

Answer (score 7):

Boost.Python has special macros that declare functions with `extern "C"` so the Python interpreter will be able to call them.  It's kind of complicated, but you can look at the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/python/doc/v2/module.html#BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE-spec) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Python declares a C-API (see http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/ or http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/). This API defines a generic object type called `PyObject` which is just a normal C struct. This structure defines (nearly) everything a python object can do, e.g., what happens when do additions or comparisons on this object or simply call it like a function.

Because python types are also objects (and therefore are represented in C by a `PyObject` structure), defining a new type is a simple matter of defining a new `PyObject` struct like that one. When methods are called in Python, the interpreter forwards the call to C functions associated with this structure.

As long as a given (compiled) extension provides the correct entry points such that the Python interpreter can introspect it and find out what is available (the documentation I indicated above does explain this in details), then it can use these objects like any other object you normally have available at the prompt - which BTW, are constructed using the very same C-API. It suffices you `import` the compiled extension.

I hope it is somewhat clear how the Python interpreter calls stuff from compiled extensions from the above. The sole missing gap is how the C-API calls the C++ code.

Boost.Python does this by declaring C entry points in code along the lines as explained here: [Elegantly call C++ from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c). Every time you call, e.g., `boost::python::class_`, it does this for the type you declare to python, creating therefore a `PyObject` that represents your class, with the name you choose. As you call `.def` on this class you go filling in the internal slots of that structure, declaring more methods, operators and attributes of your new type. Each of these internal slots points to a C-style function that is nothing but a wrapper to the equivalent C++ call.

Answer (score 2):

C++ can interoperate with C by extern "C" declarations.