# Compiling multiple languages together and calling function from one language to other

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, multiple-languages

How do I compile Multiple Programming Languages and link them together?Since each Programming language is best for some particular cases I need to use best of each language so how do I do it? Is it possible combine java with c++ or c and Python with C or C++?Is it possible to call a java or python function from c or c++ and vice versa?

Comment: It's called a [Foreign Function Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface).  The way it is implemented varies depending on which languages are being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For calling C from C++ you don't need anything special, since C++ was designed this way
- You can call C from Python by using native extensions for this you should use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) or [swig](http://www.swig.org/) read more [here](http://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html). And [here](http://blog-of-darius.blogspot.com/2011/03/simple-win32-python-and-ctypes-sample.html) is example how to call Windows API from Python.
- There is [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) for calling native C libraries from Java and vice verse read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)
- It is also possible to call C++ from C If I remember correctly you need to use "extern C" declaration in your C++ code read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c)
- It is possible to call C from JavaScript (for example native node modules)

In fact almost any language has possibility to call C libraries because of amount of C libraries and because those are easy to port from system to system. In fact many complex systems uses script language for so called glue code witch uses C libraries. Any way this is broad topic you should tell more about your problem so that we could help you. If you jest want to test concept I think the Python way is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) - although I believe that's mostly targetting the "interpreted calling compiled" case.