# Compile cpp source to run in c support only

Tags: c++, c, compilation, uefi

I want to ask about a problem about c/c++ compile 
I have project need to reuse a library wrote base on Cpp language. 
But I need to reuse the library in a project which work on a platform only support c language (UEFI) 
I want to ask :
 -Is it possible to write a wrap API in C code to call all function in the Cpp library ?

-And After compiled All of these (Wrap API, CppLibrary,My Source project) by C compiler =>Will  the build  application is working in my platform (UEFI)? "

( Assumption than both Cpp library and My project source in compile in the same compile like (visual c 2013) )

Thank you

Comment: Have you searched for an answer? There seems to be many on Stackoverflow itself as well as other sites. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c) and [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp).

Comment: Yes, I did. 
I spent my time to read through the second link. Sr about the first, I didn't find that.
My answers for my question is Possible. But I want to confirm again with another guys there.

Comment: If you know its possible then why not just trY?

Comment: by the ways, My question is about compile problem. 
Will my build application is working in my platform (only support c compile from C) with the way (Wrap C Api , Cpp Lib, C source code)

Comment: @redFIVE Yes, thank you for your concern. Because My platform will take time to setup (About 2 day). I want to make a theory checking first by confirm from an expert guy in there. And spent the time to confirm it if by myself .

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. It seems you are now saying the question is whether you can compile your scenario with a C only compiler (that is, avoid using a c++ compiler). The answer is no you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a C API to wrap the C++ library, but if the C++ library can't compile and run in a UEFI environment, this won't do you any good.