# ALSA plugin creation with help C++

Tags: c++, plugins, alsa

I am started investigation of ALSA plugin creation.

I created simple plugin with help C.
Currently I am trying to rewrite it with help C++.

I compiled it and after attemp to play wav file with help my plugin I observed error:

```
symbol _snd_pcm_test_open is not defined inside /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_test.so
```

Header file CAlsaTestPlugin.hpp:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <alsa/pcm_external.h>
#include <alsa/hwdep.h>


#define DBG(fmt, arg...)  printf("DEBUG: %s: " fmt "\n" , __FUNCTION__ , ## arg)
#define ERR(fmt, arg...)  printf("ERROR: %s: " fmt "\n" , __FUNCTION__ , ## arg)
#define WRN(fmt, arg...)  printf("WARNING: %s: " fmt "\n" , __FUNCTION__ , ## arg)

typedef struct test_plug_data
{
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    int16_t* buffer;
    u_int16_t buffer_size;
    u_int32_t pos;
}test_plug_data_t;

typedef struct snd_pcm_test
{
    snd_pcm_ioplug_t io_plug;
    struct test_plug_data* data;
}snd_pcm_test_t;


static snd_pcm_ioplug_callback_t createPlaybackCallbaks();
static void test_add_data_to_buffer(test_plug_data_t* data, int16_t value);
static int test_hw_constraint(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io);
//plugin callbacks
static int test_playback_start(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io);
static int test_playback_stop(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io);
static snd_pcm_sframes_t test_pointer(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io);
static int test_close(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io);
static int test_hw_params(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io, snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params);
static int test_prepare(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io);
static snd_pcm_sframes_t test_write(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io, const snd_pcm_channel_area_t *areas,
                                    snd_pcm_uframes_t offset, snd_pcm_uframes_t size);


int _snd_pcm_test_open(snd_pcm_t **pcmp, const char *name,
                  snd_config_t *root, snd_config_t *conf,
                  snd_pcm_stream_t stream, int mode);
```

Source file CAlsaTestPlugin.cpp

```
#include "CAlsaTestPlugin.hpp"


#define PCM_DEVICE "default"

static snd_pcm_ioplug_callback_t test_playback_callback = createPlaybackCallbaks();

snd_pcm_ioplug_callback_t createPlaybackCallbaks()
{
    snd_pcm_ioplug_callback_t result;
    result.start        = test_playback_start;
    result.stop            = test_playback_stop;
    result.pointer        = test_pointer;
    result.close        = test_close;
    result.hw_params    = test_hw_params;
    result.prepare        = test_prepare;
    result.transfer        = test_write;

    return result;
}

static int test_playback_start(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io)
{
    DBG("%s started: c:%d, f:%d, r:%d", (io->stream == SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE) ? "Capture" : "Playback", io->channels, io->format, io->rate);
    return 0;
}

int test_playback_stop(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io)
{
    DBG("%s stopped\n", (io->stream == SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE) ? "Capture" : "Playback");
    return 0;
}

snd_pcm_sframes_t test_pointer(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io)
{
    static snd_pcm_sframes_t dummy = 0;
    //DBG("%ld", dummy);
    return 2048 * (dummy = ((dummy + 1) % 4));
}

int test_close(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io)
{
    DBG("");
    return 0;
}

int test_prepare(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io)
{
    DBG("stream = %s, access = %s, format = %s, rate = %u, channels = %u, period_size = %lu, buffer_size = %lu",
        snd_pcm_stream_name(io->stream), snd_pcm_access_name(io->access), snd_pcm_format_name(io->format),
        io->rate, io->channels, io->period_size, io->buffer_size);

    test_plug_data_t* data = static_cast<test_plug_data_t*>(io->private_data);
    unsigned int pcm, tmp;
    u_int32_t rate, channels;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t period_size = 48;
    char *buff;
    int buff_size;
    rate      = io->rate;
    channels = io->channels;


    if (pcm = snd_pcm_open(&(data->pcm_handle), PCM_DEVICE, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) < 0)
    {
          printf("ERROR: Can't open \"%s\" PCM device. %s", PCM_DEVICE, snd_strerror(pcm));
    }

    /* Allocate parameters object and fill it with default values*/
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&(data->params));

    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(data->pcm_handle, data->params);

    /* Set parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(data->pcm_handle, data->params,
                SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED) < 0)
        DBG("ERROR: Can't set interleaved mode. %s", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(data->pcm_handle, data->params,
                    SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE) < 0)
        DBG("ERROR: Can't set format. %s", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(data->pcm_handle, data->params, channels) < 0)
        DBG("ERROR: Can't set channels number. %s", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(data->pcm_handle, data->params, &rate, 0) < 0)
        DBG("ERROR: Can't set rate. %s", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Write parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params(data->pcm_handle, data->params) < 0)
        DBG("ERROR: Can't set harware parameters. %s", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Resume information */
    DBG("PCM name: '%s'", snd_pcm_name(data->pcm_handle));

    DBG("PCM state: %s", snd_pcm_state_name(snd_pcm_state(data->pcm_handle)));

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(data->params, &tmp);
    DBG("channels: %i (%s)", tmp, tmp == 1 ? "mono" : "stereo");

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(data->params, &tmp, 0);
    DBG("rate: %d kHz", tmp);

    /* Allocate buffer to hold single period */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(data->params, &frames, 0);
    DBG("Period size: %lu", frames);

    buff_size = frames * channels /* 2 -> sample size */;
    data->buffer_size = buff_size;
    data->buffer = (int16_t *) malloc(data->buffer_size * 2);
    data->pos = 0;

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(data->params, &tmp, NULL);
    DBG("Period time: %lu", tmp);

    return 0;
}



int test_hw_params(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io, snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params)
{
    DBG("");
    return 0;
}

static void test_add_data_to_buffer(test_plug_data_t* data, int16_t value)
{
    data->buffer[data->pos] = value;
    //DBG("pos = %u, value = %i, data[%u] = %i", data->pos, value, data->pos, data->buffer[data->pos]);
    data->pos++;
    if(data->pos == data->buffer_size)
    {
      //DBG("Play!!!!!");

      unsigned int pcm;
      if (pcm = snd_pcm_writei(data->pcm_handle, data->buffer, data->buffer_size / 2) == -EPIPE)
      {
         DBG("XRUN");
         //snd_pcm_prepare(data->pcm_handle);
      }
      else if (pcm < 0) {
         DBG("ERROR. Can't write to PCM device. %s", snd_strerror(pcm));
      }
      else
      {
         DBG("GOOD. pcm = %u", pcm);
      }

      data->pos = 0;
    }
}

static snd_pcm_sframes_t test_write(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io,
                const snd_pcm_channel_area_t *areas,
                snd_pcm_uframes_t offset, snd_pcm_uframes_t size)
{
    static u_int32_t area_number = 0;
    test_plug_data_t* data = static_cast<test_plug_data_t*>(io->private_data);
    //DBG("area_number = %u, offset = %lu, size = %lu", area_number, offset, size);

    int16_t* value_ptr = (int16_t*)(areas[0].addr + areas[0].first / 8);
    int16_t* value_ptr2 = (int16_t*)(areas[1].addr + areas[1].first / 8);
    for(u_int32_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      test_add_data_to_buffer(data, *value_ptr );
      test_add_data_to_buffer(data, *value_ptr2 );
      value_ptr+=2;
      value_ptr2+=2;
    }

    ++area_number;
    return size;
}

static int test_hw_constraint(snd_pcm_ioplug_t *io)
{
    unsigned int access_list[] = { SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED };
    unsigned int rate_list[] = { 44100, 48000 };
    unsigned int format_list[] = { SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S32_LE };
    unsigned int period_list[] = { 6 * 8 };
    int err;

    /* access type */
    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_set_param_list(io, SND_PCM_IOPLUG_HW_ACCESS, sizeof(access_list) / sizeof(access_list[0]), access_list);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    /* supported formats */
    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_set_param_list(io, SND_PCM_IOPLUG_HW_FORMAT, sizeof(format_list) / sizeof(format_list[0]), format_list);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_set_param_minmax(io, SND_PCM_IOPLUG_HW_CHANNELS, 1, 2);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    /* supported buffer sizes*/
    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_set_param_minmax(io, SND_PCM_IOPLUG_HW_BUFFER_BYTES, period_list[0] * 2, period_list[0] * 8);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    /* supported block sizes: */
    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_set_param_list(io, SND_PCM_IOPLUG_HW_PERIOD_BYTES, sizeof(period_list) / sizeof(period_list[0]), period_list);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    /* supported rates */
    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_set_param_list(io, SND_PCM_IOPLUG_HW_RATE, sizeof(rate_list) / sizeof(rate_list[0]), rate_list);
    if (err < 0)
        return err;

    return 0;
}

SND_PCM_PLUGIN_DEFINE_FUNC(test)
{
    snd_config_iterator_t i, next;
    int err;
    snd_pcm_test_t* test_data;
    //TODO use new
    test_data = static_cast<snd_pcm_test_t*>(calloc(1, sizeof(snd_pcm_test_t)));
    if (!test_data)
      return -ENOMEM;

    test_data->data = static_cast<test_plug_data_t*>(calloc(1, sizeof(test_plug_data_t)));
    if (! test_data->data) {
      return -ENOMEM;
    }

    snd_config_for_each(i, next, conf)
    {
        snd_config_t *n = snd_config_iterator_entry(i);
        const char *id;
        if (snd_config_get_id(n, &id) < 0)
            continue;

        if (strcmp(id, "comment") == 0 || strcmp(id, "type") == 0)
            continue;
    }

    test_data->io_plug.version = SND_PCM_IOPLUG_VERSION;
    test_data->io_plug.name = "TEST PLUGIN";
    test_data->io_plug.callback = &test_playback_callback;
    test_data->data->pcm_handle = 0;
    test_data->io_plug.private_data = &test_data->data;
    err = snd_pcm_ioplug_create(&test_data->io_plug, name, stream, mode);


    err = test_hw_constraint(&test_data->io_plug);

    if (err < 0) {
      snd_pcm_ioplug_delete(&test_data->io_plug);
        goto error;
    }

    *pcmp = test_data->io_plug.pcm;
error:
    return err;
}

SND_PCM_PLUGIN_SYMBOL(test)
```

If somebody had an experience for creation ALSA plugins with using C++ please help me.

I compiled so lib with hel cmake.
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(AlsaPlugins)
MESSAGE("Building ${PROJECT_NAME}")

SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lasound -g -O2 -MD -MP -fPIC -DPIC")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Compiler options: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

ADD_LIBRARY(asound_module_pcm_test SHARED CAlsaTestPlugin.cpp)
```

added plugin configuration to .asoundrc:

```
pcm.test {
    type test
    playback_ports {
        0 alsa_pcm:playback_1
    }
    capture_ports {
        0 alsa_pcm:capture_1
    }
}
```

Installed plugin lib to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib
And then called console command to test plugin:
aplay -Drui ~/Alesis-Fusion-Nylon-String-Guitar-C4.wav > ~/out.txt

If I compile equal code with help C it works.
The main difference I compile C sources with hepl Makefile which based on Makefile from alsa_plugins project.
Added link to Makefile because mesage size imit is reached
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5n7ZdHrpqwJc0Q4dTB1VEFibDQ

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question. What have you tried? Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Hello Dister. I compiled library with help cmake. Added config in .asoundrc. And then called aplay -Dtest ~/Alesis-Fusion-Nylon-String-Guitar-C4.wav > ~/out.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegantly call C++ from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c)

Comment: Thank you very match. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is neccessary to override your ALSA plugin function definitions and type definitions with extern "C".

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
... ALSA plugin function defininitions
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

gtkiostream provides a C++ class for implementing ALSA plugins. You can use that code base for a C++ abstracted ALSA subsystem OR you can figure out what your code is missing from that code.

You inherit gtkiostream for external ALSA plugins like so :

```
#include <ALSA/ALSAExternalPlugin.H>
class ALSAExternalPluginTest : public ALSAExternalPlugin {

    virtual int specifyHWParams(){
       // you have to implement this method, similar to here : https://github.com/flatmax/gtkiostream/blob/master/test/ALSAExternalPluginTest.C#L61
       // you have now specified your data format and channels
       return 0;
    };

    virtual snd_pcm_sframes_t transfer(const snd_pcm_channel_area_t *dst_areas, snd_pcm_uframes_t dst_offset, const snd_pcm_channel_area_t *src_areas, snd_pcm_uframes_t src_offset, snd_pcm_uframes_t size){
        // use Eigen to wrap the ALSA audio buffers in Matrices for use in computation. 
        int ch=2;
        Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> stride(1,ch);
        float *srcAddr=(float*)getAddress(src_areas, src_offset);            
        float *dstAddr=(float*)getAddress(dst_areas, dst_offset);            
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>, 
              Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> >                                                                          
                                                 in(srcAddr, size, ch, stride);
        Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>, 
              Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::Stride<Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> >
                  out(dstAddr, size, ch, stride);

        // copy the input audio to the output audio - you should implement your algorithm here
        out=in;
        return size;
    }
};
```

You define your plugin like so :

```
ALSAExternalPluginTest aEPlugin;
extern "C" SND_PCM_PLUGIN_DEFINE_FUNC(ALSAExternalPluginTest){
    std::cout<<__func__<<std::endl;
    aEPlugin.parseConfig(name, conf, stream, mode);

    int ret=aEPlugin.create(name, root, stream, mode);
    if (ret<0)
        return ret;

    aEPlugin.specifyHWParams();

    *pcmp=aEPlugin.getPCM();
    std::cout<<__func__<<" returning "<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

SND_PCM_PLUGIN_SYMBOL(ALSAExternalPluginTest);
```

Here are example flags for compilation with g++ (include libasound2 flags as well) :

```
CPPFLAGS = $(EIGEN_CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -export-dynamic -no-undefined
```